# mysql_fetch_assoc in MeekroDB

Tags: mysql, row, fetch

Excuse me for being new to MeekroDB library, I wonder how to check for rows in the login process;

```sql
$query = DB::query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s",$username);
$numrows = DB::count($query);

// this needs the edit
         if ($numrows!=0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $dbusername = $row['username'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bear in mind that your variable $query is now an array (if any records are found) so you do not need to do

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
```

Instead try

```
foreach ($query as $user) 
{
    $dbusername = $user['username'];
    $dbpassword = $user['password'];
}
```

Also, if you have more then one record with the same username and password then you may be doing something wrong with your user registration/maintenance process.